# FTP Upload Android

Tags: android, upload, ftp

I want to upload a file from the sdcard to my FTP Server.
The download part works well, but if I run the upload method it does not throw any exception just says that *upload was successfull*.

Unfortunately nothing appears on my FTP Server in Folder test2 or anywhere.

**My Upload Method:**

```
public boolean ftpUpload(String srcFilePath, String desFileName,
        String desDirectory) {
    boolean status = false;
    try {
        FileInputStream srcFileStream = new FileInputStream(srcFilePath);

        // change working directory to the destination directory
        if (ftpChangeDirectory(desDirectory)) {
            status = mFTPClient.storeFile(desFileName, srcFileStream);
        }

        srcFileStream.close();
        System.out.println("upload success");

        return status;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("upload failed");
    }

    return status;
}
```

}

**and this is how I call the function:**

`ftpUpload("/mnt/sdcard/index.php", "index.php","/test2");`

//ftpUpload(srcFilePath, desFileName, desDirectory);

Thanks for help.